# JSON escaping slashes in a file path, wont display image

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, escaping

I'm using PHP and a `for` loop to prepare data into proper `html` and output the data using `JSON` to be `appended` and displayed on the page. `JSON` slash escaping is causing the html to be viewed incorrectly by the browser.

This is my PHP for loop:

```
$json = '<div id="rsec3" class="rsec">';
for($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++)
{
    $coverart = $array[$i]['cover'];
    if(empty($coverart))
    {
        $coverart = "nocoverart.gif";
    }
    $json .= '<div><img="/video/cover/thumbs/' . $cover . '"></div>';
}
$json .= '</div>';

$json = json_encode(array('ok' => 'ok', 'html' => $json));
echo $json;
```

This is my javascript parsing and appending the json:

```
$.get('/index_get.php?iid='+this.id,function(data){
    $('#indload').hide();
    js=jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    $('#indr').append(js.html);
});
```

This is what the browser is displaying, a bunch of useless jargon, and it is appending a `</img=">` on its own?

```
<img=" video cover thumbs img.png"></img=">
```

How can I prevent this from occuring, and having the image displayed properly?

Comment: Can you post the contents of $array?

Comment: don't need to call `$.parseJSON` if you use `$.getJSON` instead of `$.get` or just add datatype to `$.get`

Comment: the only value of the array of significance is `cover` which outputs a name of an image such as `img.png` or `lolwut.gif` etc

Comment: you need to close the image tag in your string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem could be invalid HTML tag `<img>` on the php code. In the `<img>` tag, `src` is missing and `<img>` tag was not closed.

Change the following

```
$json .= '<div><img="/video/cover/thumbs/' . $cover . '"></div>';
```

to

```
$json .= '<div><img src="/video/cover/thumbs/' . $cover . '" /></div>';
```

Comment: what a silly mistake to make, why i shouldnt code late at night ;)

Answer (score -1):

you need to close the image tag in your string

```
$json .= '<div><img="/video/cover/thumbs/' . $cover . '"/></div>';
```